# mysqli_affected_rows() always returns -1

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, xdebug

In my development environment, all calls to mysqli_affected_rows($link) are unexpectedly returning -1, indicating an error of some sort.

The identical SQL executed from a SQL console works as expected.

To avoid people trying to understand the code, I have written rewritten this question with a very simple test script, as follows:

```
<?php
// $DB parameters deleted
$link = @mysqli_connect($DBHOSTNAME, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
$query = 'UPDATE control SET message = 66476 WHERE controlid = "lastgood"';
$rs = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$nbr = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
echo $nbr;
?>
```

This script returns -1. Something in my environment is clobbering mysqli_affected_rows().

Comment: Show your code please. Maybe you're just using it wrong.

Comment: −1 indicates an error, so what's the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. The $err var is blank.

Comment: Because this is not a problem about code, I have written a test script and replaced the original question with the test script for clarity.

Comment: _“The $err var is blank”_ – there is no $err in your code. Please rewrite that example to actually include proper error handling. // And have you checked whether or not the update has actually happened by looking at the database records before/after?

Comment: Well, if you're silencing `mysqli_connect`, that might be why you don't have any errors. Check `$link->connect_error` as well. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: And if that doesn’t help, then echo out `mysqli_info()` as well, that might have more information.

Comment: I appreciate all the sincere effort to help. People are misunderstanding this question. They are trying to debug code. The code has been in place for many years, and all the SQL operations to update the data are working. The row gets updated. The only thing that is not working is that IN THE DEBUG ENVIRONMENT ONLY mysqli_affected_rows returns -1. There are no errors returned from the mysql call. All the SQL except apparently this one function is working. The $err referred to in the original code, which I simplified and removed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug documented at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67348 with mysqli_affected_rows when operating through a debugger.

Comment: Good to know, +1 for the find. However, since these kinds of bugs are extremely rare and it's much much much more common for people to simply write bad code, you should be providing a sample in your question which categorically rules out all other explanations before anyone goes off on a bug hunt in the PHP source. It'd be great if you could update your question with such an iron clad example so this answer can stand as universally helpful documentation.